# Subsonic T4 TextTemplatingService Exception on VS 2005

Tags: serialization, visual-studio-2005, subsonic3, t4

I have a VS2005 web application I am using the MySQL active record templates and is perfectly working in VS2008 however I get this error:

```
Custom tool error: An Exception was thrown while running the transformation code. The process cannot continue.  The following Exception was thrown:
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.VSHost.TextTemplatingService' in Assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.VSHost, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' is not marked as serializable.
```

View Full Exception Details:
http://pastebin.com/rF8iQJW2

I have the following packages installed to make it work for vs2005:

http://goo.gl/uINkV
Guidance Automation Toolkit for Visual Studio 2005 - February 2008 Release

http://goo.gl/OEUNP
Guidance Automation Extensions - February 2008 Release

Comment: Subsonic 3.0 doesn't work for VS2005 as it requires .NET framework 3.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subsonic 3.0 doesn't work for VS2005 as it requires .NET framework 3.5

Answer (score 0):

Previous answer is not correct.  The T4 system now runs out of process and sets up an Ipc channel back to the Host.  This transport channel ( based on remoting ) uses a Binary serializer and cannot  transport the Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.VSHost.TextTemplatingService over that channel because it is not marked as serializable, exactly as the exception message says.

Incidently, you can get access to this service by changing the template directive hostspecific="true" and accessing the "Host" property.

There are also some parts of the EnvDTE.DTE that cannot be accessed via T4 templates for the same reason ( like DTE.Windows or DTE.WindowConfiguration ).